# Sporadic Noise Generated from AD5791 DAC Driven by DE10-Nano

Tags: analog, fpga, noise, dac

I'm working with a system that allows me to set voltage waveforms on a PC and output them on the AD5791 DAC (eval board), with the DE10-Nano SoC/FPGA acting as an intermediary between the two. The HDL design on the DE10 contains a buffer (Intel's FIFO IP component). Its original depth is 4096 words. I want to make the buffer deeper.

So I did that and got a bizarre problem. The outputted voltages, which used to be clean signals, became oddly noisy. There are random jumps (about 1 ms each) from the expected pattern, sometimes isolated, sometimes a large cluster. Sometimes the output is mostly clean, while other times the entire signal is corrupted. It appears at random. Here are some examples.

[image: A very noisy output sequence]
*A very noisy output sequence*
[image: A cleaner output sequence]
*A cleaner output sequence*
[image: Zoomed in view of the noise]
*Zoomed in view of the noise*
[image: Zoomed in view of a single noise event]
*Zoomed in view of a single noise event*

The only pattern I can discern is that the larger the buffer depth, the greater the signal corruption tends to be (the deepest buffer I can make is ~131,000 words). Also, it seems that that linear waveforms are somewhat cleaner than curvy ones. Curiously making the buffer shallower than its original 4096 words doesn't seem to adversely affect it. Changing the buffer depth (a single drop-down menu in the IP manager) is the only change I've made to the whole setup.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. It would be impossible for me to describe the entire FPGA project here (particularly since I don't fully comprehend it). However, I am wondering if this is somehow a common problem or whether someone with greater expertise can discern some underlying issue. At the very least, what threads can I pursue to narrow down the problem and attempt to fix it? If there is anything I can provide to be more helpful, please let me know.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Check the latched data input

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Do you mean the buffer input? And is there any reason that the data would suddenly become "garbage" when the buffer is enlarged?

Comment: Digital in ,analog out,, check the data going into the DAC to validate the timing then the data being sent.  Check the stack pointer is valid.

Comment: Try halving clock frequency and see if it improves the picture. I would not call this garbage, as there's clearly specific patterns of bits falling out being set to 1. Are there're any warnings when project is being compiled? Larger buffer will employ more memory cells, with more logic, with increased delays in write and read cycles - and this is what you may see - some data not arriving in time to or from the buffer RAMs.

Comment: It does seem to be the case that the noise is proportional to the clock frequency. There are quite a few warnings upon compilation. Perhaps I should look at those more closely?